# grep including new line

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have a log file, and I want to get the content using pattern

Log file will look like this

```
2019-05-15 16:40 +07:00: data { data:
   [ { audio_incremental_num: 1,
       session_id: 'openrJEe7A_1557912549',
       stream_time: 88,
       duration: 291,
       audio_id: '749f7c75-9fe1-4dbc-b5d8-770aadfe94bc'
       version: '1.2' },
     { audio_incremental_num: 1,
       session_id: 'openrJEe7A_1557912549',
       stream_time: 88,
       duration: 291,
       audio_id: '749f7c75-9fe1-4dbc-b5d8-770aadfe94bc'
       version: '1.2' }] }
2019-05-15 16:50 +07:00: data { data:
   [ { audio_incremental_num: 1,
       session_id: 'openrJEe7A_1557912549',
       stream_time: 88,
       duration: 291,
       audio_id: '749f7c75-9fe1-4dbc-b5d8-770aadfe94bc'
       version: '1.2' },
     { audio_incremental_num: 1,
       session_id: 'openrJEe7A_1557912549',
       stream_time: 88,
       duration: 291,
       audio_id: '749f7c75-9fe1-4dbc-b5d8-770aadfe94bc'
       version: '1.2' }] }
```

I have tried using these but no luck

```
grep -zo '2019-05-[0-9][1-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] +07:00: data { data:[[:space:]]'

grep -P '2019-05-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} \+07:00: data { data:(\s.*)*.*'
```

Note: My log file actually is mixed with other log string content, so its not 100% JSON log

Answer (score 0):

Your log file look like a json format you can use jq in bash to parse that is very useful check this link [Working with JSON in bash using `jq`](https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/working-with-json-in-bash-using-jq-13d76d307c4)

Comment: actually my log file is mixed with other log content, so its not 100% json log

Comment: can you post the full log